# How to fix "extended" partition in Windows 7?

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, multi-boot, mbr

I have created a (supposedly) logical FAT partition on an MBR disk, in the "extended" area using Linux. Afterwards, Windows (on the same machine) storage manager gets confused and doesn't see the extended partition properly, presenting all previous "logical" partitions as primary.

As I've already copied a large amount of data to the new partition, I would like to "fix" the way Windows sees the extended partition as it was before.

**EDIT**

Basically, there is a discrepancy between "Disk Management" "snap-in" GUI and "actual" situation (whatever they might be). I'll let the following speak for itself:

```
DISKPART> list part

Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
-------------  ----------------  -------  -------
Partition 1    Primary            100 MB  1024 KB
Partition 2    Primary            128 GB   101 MB
Partition 3    Primary              8 GB   128 GB
Partition 0    Extended           329 GB   136 GB
Partition 4    Logical              8 GB   136 GB
Partition 5    Logical              8 GB   144 GB
Partition 6    Logical           4096 MB   152 GB
Partition 7    Logical             64 GB   156 GB
Partition 8    Logical            245 GB   220 GB

DISKPART>
```

[image: Windows Disk Management snap-in graphical view]

Comment: With MBR, partitions 1 thru 4 are primary and extended must be one of them. Not 0 as you are showing. And 4 cannot be logical. Logicals always start at 5. Post this from Linux: `sudo parted -l` and `lsblk -e7 -f`

Comment: @oldfred given your use of "must be" and "can not" while commenting on a command output, are you suggesting there's a bug? Note that the command output is from Windows.

Comment: Those are the rules for MBR. Windows has its own rules? I know Windows will rewrite a partition table and conveniently "forget" to include Linux partitions. Since Windows 7 and still there with Windows 10 if install is MBR.  Need to see parted output.

Comment: @oldfred i don't believe there was a "rewrite". I'm sharpening my sword  and pointing it at the GUI. BTW, Win does have its own rules, in the form of quantisation of units MB and GB. I am also pointing a sword at Linux, since it is able to make a "partition" occupy a whole disk, and this might have impact on the "extended partition" paradigm.

Comment: Windows has dynamic partition and Linux has similar LVM volumes that occupy one partition. But it is Windows that confused "drives". In Windows a d: drive can be a second partition on sda or sda2 or the first partition on a second drive or sdb1. In Linux the drive is unique to a physical device and partitions then are parts withing that device.I started converting to gpt in 2010 and have only used gpt since on new or repartitioned drives. Windows only installs to gpt with UEFI boot mode. From 2010: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457901

Comment: @oldfred that's the bigger problem, I couldn't figure out if Win 7 supported UEFI or not, otherwise wouldn't be in this mess

Comment: @AgnesK.Cathex Windows 7 supports UEFI if installed with a properly made USB media.

Comment: Windows only boots from gpt partitioned drives with UEFI and only from MBR(msdos) partitioned drives with BIOS. So if drive is MBR, then install is BIOS. Original Windows 7 installer required copy to flash drive & move of some files to make it UEFI bootable to install in UEFI mode. Update I believe fixed that, so Windows 7 installer can be booted in either mode. How you boot install media for Windows & Linux is then how it installs.